What do other Star Trek races call their FTL tech?
In Star Trek, the Federation use the term 'warp speed' to describe their FTL technology, presumably because it works by distorting/warping the 'real space' around the ship so that the ship can overcome the universal constant that nothing can travel faster than light.
The matter/antimatter reactor they use to power this is then often referred to as 'the warp core'. I'm aware that Romulan ships use an artificial quantum singularity to power their ships.
Is it ever mentioned in the shows or films if other races FTL tech is the same, i.e. do Romulans and Klingons also use 'warp fields' to distort the nature of space around them to allow for speeds greater than light, and do they refer it to as 'warp speed' or something else?

Well, whatever they call it, once it runs through the Universal Translator...

There are thousands of known races in the Star Trek fictional canon. It is a bit extravagant to expect us to name the term "warp drive" or "warp speed" in everyone of these instances

Are you asking about various names for "warp" styles of FTL, or are you asking about what different "non-warp" styles of FTL exist?

The Pakled call it woooooooooooooooooshh

Generally, yes everyone is using the same warp physics. In fact the designers of the Original series Klingon and Romulan ships made a point of making the ships have analogous features.
A point that is never mentioned however is that technically a 'warp factor" should vary widely between different ship designs.  The Original Star Trek and TNG had deliberately different warp scales that presumably reflected a technological advancement.  However surely some civilizations would be using the TOS style technology as a minimum difference.  (Warp factors are speeds that are easier for the engine to be at than the adjacent speeds.  For example being at Warp 2 which is 10X lightspeed uses less energy than 9x or 11x lightspeed.)
This is a very obvious spot where a script could have had a universal translation problem.  But I suppose we just assume if a Klingon says Warp 5 it is the same as a Federation Warp 5.
There are a few examples of notably different physics like this.  But it is a rare example.  https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Quantum_slipstream_drive
Also, you have a false premise.  Space is not being warped.  Subspace is - that is to say a Trek warp drive with it's fictional elements is not the same as the Alcubierre drive of theoretical physics.
In the Star Trek pilot they used the term "time-warp" - though arguably even at that point it was not in-universe well understood what was happening. Certainly it was later established in TNG.
From TNG Technical Manual Chapter 5 Warp Propulsion.

"The key to the creation of subsequent non-Newtonian
methods, i.e., propulsion not dependent upon exhausting
reaction products, lay in the concept of nesting many layers of
warp field energy, each layer exerting a controlled amount of
force against its next-outermost neighbor. The cumulative
effect of the force applied drives the vehicle forward and is
known as asymmetrical peristaltic field manipulation (APFM).
Warp field coils in the engine nacelles are energized in
sequential order, fore to aft. The firing frequency determines
the number of field layers, a greater number of layers per unit
time being required at higher warp factors. Each new field
layer expands outward from the nacelles, experiences a rapid
force coupling and decoupling at variable distances from the
nacelles, simultaneously transferring energy and separating
from the previous layer at velocities between 0.5c and 0.9c.
This is well within the bounds of traditional physics, effectively
circumventing the limits of General, Special, and Transformational Relativity. During force coupling the radiated energy
makes the necessary transition into subspace, applying an
apparent mass reduction effect to the spacecraft. This
facilitates the slippage of the spacecraft through the sequencing layers of warp field energy"


Warp drives are by no means exclusive to Starfleet. They're the predominant means of interstellar travel within the Alpha Quadrant, used by species including but not limited to humans, Klingons, Vulcans, Romulans, Cardassians and Ferengi.

PICARD: Ah. We've received new directives from the Federation Council on this matter. Until we can find a way to counteract the warp field effect, the Council feels our best course is to slow the damage as much as possible. Therefore, areas of space found susceptible to warp fields will be restricted to essential travel only, and effective immediately all Federation vessels will be limited to a speed of warp five, except in cases of extreme emergency.
WORF: The Klingons will observe these restrictions, but the Romulans will not.
TROI: And what about the Ferengi? And the Cardassians, for that matter?
PICARD: The Federation's sharing all our data with warp-capable species. We can only hope that they realise it's in their own interests and take similar action.



Star Trek: The Next Generation - S07E09 - "Force of Nature"

The Jem'Hadar of the Gamma Quadrant were also said to use warp technology.

WORF: If the Jem'Hadar could be forced to drop out of warp for only ten minutes, they would not have time to catch up with us before we rendezvous with the Defiant.
MARTOK: A fine theory, but how do we execute it?
WORF: We could disrupt their warp fields with an inverse graviton burst. It would force them to drop to impulse until the gravitons dissipated.
KOLANA: We would need to generate a massive burst to disrupt the warp fields of a fleet that size.
WORF: A single bird of prey could do it by diverting warp power to the main deflector.
MARTOK: How long would that delay them?
KOLANA: They could reinitialise their warp cores in less than two minutes.



Star Trek: Deep Space Nine - S07E07 - "Once More Unto the Breach"

The Borg use transwarp coils and conduits, which allow their vessels to travel at speeds far greater than those of the aforementioned species, but transwarp technology isn't exclusive to the Borg either; the Voth have transwarp tech as well.

VEER: It's the plasma signature. Scanners have found a match. A ship ninety light years away. There are one hundred forty eight lifeforms aboard, travelling at warp six point two.
GEGEN: I'm engaging spatial displacement It's unlikely their primitive sensors will be able to detect us once we're out of phase. Take us out of transwarp, we don't want to pass them.



Star Trek: Voyager - S03E23 - "Distant Origin"


Possible additional point - While transwarp is poorly described and may be a bucket term for more than one technology - it seems to me to still be based on subspace like regular warp.  TOS had a once used term called "multiwarp" that may by synonymous.

This indicates that other planets/species have warp drive technology, but doesn't address what they call it.

The Borg call their's "Transwarp", but then, The Borg aren't really a "race" per se.
Also, Transwarp conveniently breaks the "speed of warp" barrier, much like warp breaks the "speed of light" barrier.

This answer contradicts itself. In the first line, you suggest that transwarp is the Borg term for warp speed. But in the second line, you acknowledge that transwarp is beyond warp speed, meaning that they're not actually the same thing. The implication of your second line is correct: transwarp is to warp speed what FTL is to the speed of light, or what supersonic is to the speed of sound, i.e. it's a higher level of speed and therefore not an equivalent term.

The question asks about FTL. Both warp and transwarp are faster than light, only varying in degrees.

I guess it depends how you interpret the question, but even if you read it as inviting apples to oranges comparisons such as this, transwarp isn't really a Borg term per se. It's a term Starfleet itself uses for anything that can move at faster-than-warp speed, including stuff they themselves utilise, such as transwarp beaming.

Indeed. If aliens call warp something else, then they would call transwarp something else else.

Transwarp does not break any warp barrier.  It exceeds the energy efficiency of primitive engines.  A Ferrari doesn't break the Model T's internal combustion engine barrier - it is vastly faster than a Model T.  In the Borg's case they also started using conduits which is kind of like wormholes so that's a different subject - but it still uses subspace.
